# Vue-cli Library target Typescript cannot find module

Tags: typescript, types, vuejs3, vue-cli

everyone, I have an issue of importing new vue3 library that I have created with vue-cli 4 and typescript.

I build the lib with  `vue-cli-service build --target lib src/index.ts` everything works  fine.

For testing i build a tgz with  `npm pack` and

I import the lib to another project with  `yarn add xxxxx/Xxxxx/xxxx/vue-auth-social-0.1.4.tgz`

in the sample project I just import a component Auth in a Home.vue

`import { Auth } from 'vue-auth-social';`

VsCode recognize the type definition however I get this bellow. Any idea?

```
cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/index.js?!./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts:7 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'vue-auth-social'
    at webpackMissingModule (cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/index.js?!./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts:7)
    at eval (cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/index.js?!./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts:7)
    at Module../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/index.js?!./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts (app.js:1195)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (Home.vue?eea5:1)
    at Module../src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts (app.js:2090)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (Home.vue?ab8c:1)
```

package.json

```
"name": "vue-auth-social",
  "version": "0.1.4",
  "private": false,
  "files": [
    "dist/*",
    "types/*"
  ],
  "types": "./types/index.d.ts",
  "main": "./dist/vue-social-auth.umd.js",
  "module": "./dist/vue-social-auth.common.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/vue-social-auth.common.js",
      "require": "./dist/vue-social-auth.umd.js"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --https true",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "build-lib": "vue-cli-service build --target lib src/index.ts",
    "build-lib-pack": "vue-cli-service build --target lib src/index.ts && npm pack",
    "push": "npm publish --access public",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  }
```

index.ts

```
export { default as Auth } from './components/Auth.vue';
export { default as FacebookAuth } from './components/FacebookAuth.vue';
export { default as GoogleAuth } from './components/GoogleAuth.vue';
export { default as SignIn } from './components/SignIn.vue';
export { default as SignUp } from './components/SignUp.vue';
```

types/index.ts

````
declare module 'vue-auth-social' {
  import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue';
  export const Auth: DefineComponent;
  export const GoogleAuth: DefineComponent;
  export const FacebookAuth: DefineComponent;
  export const SignIn: DefineComponent;
  export const SignUp: DefineComponent;
}

```
````

Comment: Do you have the `vue-auth-social` package installed? Your `package.json` doesn't show nay dependencies.

Comment: Hello tony19 thanks for replying, yes i have the package install in the sample project yarn add xxxxx/Xxxxx/xxxx/vue-auth-social-0.1.4.tgz